# Burninate [google-chrome-devtoolssql] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

A total and outstanding number of [**one** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtoolssql) is tagged with [google-chrome-devtoolssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtoolssql). Can we rip it?

I see absolutely no reason behind separating [google-chrome-devtoolssql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtoolssql) from [google-chrome-devtool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtool).

Comment: It will be automatically deleted after a year (I think) if no other question uses it... As the question is relatively new, _might_ the tag be useful or used in the future?

Comment: If you remove the tag from that question the tag will be removed at 03:00 UTC by the cleanup script.

Comment: @Ben As I expressed in my question, Chrome Dev Tools is relatively small toolset and making extra tag, here on SO, just for one of its pane / tab / feature seems pointless. At least for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I maybe jumped to conclusions but I removed the tag from that question. The tag will be removed at 03:00 UTC when the clean-up script runs.